# $a+bx \leq f(x)$ for increasing and convex function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an interval and $f:I \to \mathbb R$ increasing and convex.

How can  I show that $f$ is bounded from below by an affine function, i.e. there exist $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $a+bx \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in I$?

What similiar statement would we have for concave function?

Comment: @MartinR I don't think so, it looks different and doesn't use that $f$ is increasing

Comment: Here is another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1959851/42969. As demonstrated in the answers, $f(x) \ge f(x_0) + c(x-x_0)$ holds for all $c$ between $f_-'(x_0)$ and $f_+'(x_0)$. It only remains to show that those one-sided derivatives are somewhere positive if $f$ is (strictly) increasing.

Comment: @MartinR In my case, do we need $x_0=0$? So that $c$ is multiplied with $x$. (because in my task $b$ gets multiplied with $x$ intstead of $x-x_0$)

Comment: @obvth213: $f(x_0) + c(x-x_0) = (f(x_0) -c x_0) + cx$, so $x_0$ is not relevant.