# Example of positive, strictly concave, strictly decreasing function?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am looking for an example of a positive, strictly concave, strictly decreasing function. The standard ones, exponentials and logs do not seem to work.

Comment: You can do this easily if you restrict the domain of the function.  $f(x)=1-x^2$ is positive, strictly concave and strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of this argument is adapted from
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1959851/213690.

Suppose (i) for some real $a,$ the function
$f \colon (a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is concave.  By the definition
of concavity, if $a<y<x<z,$ then
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \geqslant \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x},
$$
the left hand side of this inequality is a non-increasing function
of $y,$ and the right hand side is a non-increasing function of $z.$
Therefore, the left hand derivative $f'_-(x)$ and right hand
derivative $f'_+(x)$ exist, and for all $y\in(a,x)$ and $z>x,$
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \geqslant f'_-(x) \geqslant f'_+(x) \geqslant
\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}.
$$

Let $x$ be any number ${>}a,$ and let $m_x$ be any number such that
$$
f'_-(x) \geqslant m_x \geqslant f'_+(x).
$$
Then for all $y\in(a,x)$ and $z>x,$
$$
f(x)-f(y) \geqslant m_x(x-y) \text{ and }
f(z)-f(x) \leqslant m_x(z-x).
$$
Equivalently,
$$
f(y) \leqslant f(x) + m_x(y-x) \text{ for all } y>a.
$$

Now suppose also (ii) $f$ is non-increasing on $(a,\infty).$ Then
$f(x)-f(y)\leqslant0$ for all $y\in(a,x),$ whence $m_x\leqslant0.$

Finally, suppose also (iii) $f$ is non-negative on $(a,\infty).$
Then for all $z>x,$
$$
0 \geqslant \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} \geqslant \frac{-f(x)}{z-x}
\to 0 \text{ as } z \to \infty.
$$
Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0,$
$$
0 \geqslant m_x \geqslant -\varepsilon.
$$
Therefore $m_x = 0.$

Therefore $f(y) \leqslant f(x)$ for all $y>a.$ But $x$ was
arbitrary.  Therefore $f$ is a constant function.  Therefore $f$ is
not strictly decreasing.

Summarising: a non-negative concave function on $(a,\infty)$ is not
strictly decreasing.  If it is only hypothesised to be non-increasing,
then it is constant.